# Python, BeautifulZoup, Selenium webscrape

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape some property information from a website (www.hotpads.com).

I'm loading in a url with a number of listings (eg [link](https://hotpads.com/baltimore-md/apartments-for-rent/map?price=700&propertyTypes=house-townhouse&listingTypes=rental&maxCreated=24&orderBy=activated)) and from that trying to go into each property and get some more detail to download into Excel.

If I 'inspect' the elements I can see the href links are identified with a class of 'Linker' once the page is loaded but if I load the page with Selenium, ensure it is loaded and then search for these links there are not there.

What am I doing wrong?  Could you give me a pointer for how to go about this.  Please note, I am waiting for the page to be loaded.  If I right click and view the link I can see what I'm after but if I view page source the links are not there.

In terms of getting and access the individual links, this is my code:

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

data = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'Linker'})
if DEBUG:
    for d in data:
        print url_base+d['href']

for d in data:
    if DEBUG: print d

    #set the link value and open it
    link = url_base+d['href']
    driver.get(link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Selenium` + `requests` in such way as `driver.get(url)` and `requests.get(url)` are two different `GET` requests (there is no correlation between them) and `time.sleep(10)` will not affect on `response = requests.get(url)`. Also it seem that target elements are dynamically generated by some `JavaScript`, so you cannot get them with `requests.get(url)` as they are not present in initial `HTML` code

Try to get page source as follow:

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: I am an idiot.  I've written a dozen scripts using the two together and always followed the approach you've specified.  I was using a BeautifulSoup only script as a basis to change and failed to notice I hadn't done this.  Thank you